# FILTER and SUMX in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I would like to add a filter option in the code below. How to get around this ? many thanks in advance.

```
_RateMeasure = SUMX(myDF,
                    myDF[Amount]*RELATED('Currency Conversion'[RateCol1]))
```

what I am trying seems not filtering properly

```
  _RateMeasure = SUMX(FILTER(myDF, myDF[COL] = "ABC"), 
                      myDF[Amount]*RELATED('Currency Conversion'[RateCol1]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
_RateMeasure =
CALCULATE (
    SUMX (
        myDF,
        myDF[Amount]
            * RELATED ( 'Currency Conversion'[RateCol1] )
    ),
    FILTER (
        myDF,
        myDF[COL] = "ABC"
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks, it should work. but i guess the problem is  created table ('Currency Conversion') which is not filtering. Eventhough, i set up the relationship in the data model.

Answer (score 1):

Your measure should work as expected. Considering that the version without filter works, that there are no page/report/visual level filters, that there is a direct relationship between the table containing myDF and the 'Currency Conversion' table, and that COL does have "ABC" values, you can check few things:

- check the data types: myDF[Amount] should be a numeric type to multiply by the currency rate, and the filter condition (myDF[COL] = "ABC") should be applied to a text column
- if 'Currency Conversion'[RateCol1] or myDF[Amount] contains BLANK or error values, the multiplication might not behave as expected.