# Filtering and data modelling in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data model as below

[image]

_Slicer Table

```
Currency  FY23 AOP   FY24 AOP
CNY       0.5         0.7
CAN       0.75        0.8
USD       1           1
EUR       1.2         1.1
```

_factinput(test) table is in the mid

```
Currency   Amount  A/B
EU         10       A
USD        10       A
CNY        10       A
USD        10       B
CNY        10       B
```

Expected Answer

```
_rate_conversion_AOP_FY24 = 10*1.1 + 10*1 + 10*0.7
```

What I am trying [to do is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78057498/filter-and-sumx-in-dax/78057899#78057899) but it is not filtering probably.

```
_RateMeasure =
CALCULATE (
    SUMX (
        facttable,
        facttable[Amount]
            * RELATED ( '_SlicerTable'[FY24 AOP] )
    ),
    FILTER (
        facttable,
        facttable[COL] = "A"
    )
)
```

Am I missing something in the data model regarding to `_SlicerTable` ? many thanks in advance.